# PHP shell_exec stops working

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell-exec

I am experiencing a problem with PHP **shell_exec()**.

Background:
I've used **shell_exec()** to access an Embedded Linux target *(ie. Raspberry Pi)* via a web browser, using HTML JavaScript (AJAX) and PHP which all works really well (as i am aware of the security issues around this. but doesn’t apply to do this). Currently I am using **PHP v 5.6.31** and **Apache2 v 2.4.27** which seem stable.

Problem 
After extended use i'm noticing that **shell_exec()** becomes non-responsive? The following example is logged in `/var/apache2/logs/error_log`

> …PHP Warning:  shell_exec(): Unable to execute ‘/sbin/ifconfig ….

The web server is still actively working and serving pages to the browser. I can execute ifconfig via a terminal window (SSH/serial) which works. Shell_exec() functionality is not restored until Apache2 services are restarted. I've updated the Apache2 and PHP. but this has not resolved the issue.

I've read around this and suspect that resources might be the issue, ie garbage collection. I've tried updating the following values in `php.ini` `(session.gc_probability, session.gc_divisor)` but no luck.

Your suggestions / experience on the matter would be appreciated :)

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: does anyone of any methods of extracting data. Im getting the feeling that PHP + Apache is a slow and expensive (resource hungry) way of querying a embedded linux target

Comment: ...looks like using websockets is a better way of implementing this process of query the system.

Comment: I retract my previous statement, looks like the exec problem is still there with websockets. Currently getting `PHP: Warning:  exec(): Unable to fork [pwd] in /path/to/websocket_server.php`

Answer (score 0):

did you try to changes the permission of script to allow apache / PHP application to access it ?

Answer (score 0):

shell_exec() will wait for the script it executes to finish running before continuing.
So whatever your executing is the problem.

Comment: point taken on board but its not the case for this one. issue still present when using other applications